# 2d array to count how many ones in each column/row in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

## I have this so far which counts how many ones in the whole array but i want to count how many ones in all of the columns and the ones in all of the rows separately

```
#include <stdio.h>
void countcolumn(int a[10][10]){
int i,j,flag=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        if(a[i][j]==1){
            flag=flag+1;
        }
    
    }
    
}
printf("\n%d\n",flag);

}

int one[10][10]={0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    1,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    1,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0};
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: If you want to count the number of ones in each column and row, then each column and row will require its own counter.

Comment: yeah i know i need to initialize two counter but i cant get the idea like how should i do it @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i want to count the number of ones in each column then count the number of ones in each row separately did you get it?

Comment: @RAMA I understand this but I do not understand what the question is.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow oh, i need someone to help me with it because i can’t figure it out

Comment: @RAMA: Why two counters? You have 10 columns and 10 rows, so why not 20 counters, one for each column and row?

Comment: Is the question how to create and use an array of counters?

Comment: Isn’t 20 too much? @AndreasWenzel

Comment: 10 for rows and 10 for columns right?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan no, i am trying to count number of ones in the array, i want to count the numbers of ones in the array column then count the number of ones in the array rows, so if i initialized two counter, one to save the number of ones in the columns, and one to save the number of ones in the rows isn’t that true?

Comment: yes the array is size 10x10

Comment: im stuck at the for loop thing, like how to do a for loop only for the rows and the same as columns

Comment: Umm.  They will be the same?  You access all the rows and all the columns to count both right?  Just the order you visit each part of the array is different?  You can do that by just switching i and j in your array read. -> `count1 += a[i][j] == 1; count2 += a[j][i] == 1`

Comment: @RAMA: In your question, you stated that you wanted to count the number of ones in **each** column and in **each** row. However, in your comment, you state that you only want two counters, one for counting the number of ones in (all of) the columns and one for counting the number of ones in (all of) the rows. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I mean that i want to do 2 functions, one function called countcolumns it will only count the number of ones in the columns of the 2d array, and another function called countrows it will only count the number of rown in a 2d array, is it more clear now?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel this is what i mean exactly,sorry my english is not that good, but i mean that i want to count ones in all of the columns in the 2d array, and count the number of ones in all of the rows in the array

Comment: This is going to be closed.  Consider re-asking exactly what you are looking for.  Your clarification here still doesn't make any sense to me.  Counting by columns or by rows is still counting every element of the 2D array.  If you mean you want to count individual columns or individual rows in a given 2D array, then state that.

Comment: Im sorry if i couldnt explain good, but what exactly i want to do is that i want to create 2 functions, pass a 2d array of size 10x10 to the two functions, one of the functions is called countcolumns which is only going to count the number of ones in the columns of the whole array, the other function is called countrows and its going to count the number of ones in the rows of the whole array, is this more clear now?

Comment: @RAMA: The number of ones in the entire array will be the same, whether you traverse the array in [row-major or column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). Therefore, your functions `countcolumn` and `countrow` will yield the same results. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel but the array is filled with zeors and ones so how is it going to return the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass each row and count the number of ones.
and then to pass each column and count the number of ones.

```
void countONE(int a[10][10]){
    int i,j,counter=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(a[i][j]==1)
                counter++;
            }
        printf("Row %d have %d one values.\n",i,counter);
        counter=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(a[j][i]==1)
                counter++;
            }
        printf("Column %d have %d one values.\n",i,counter);
        counter=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Hadeel can i email you for further questions on this, because this helped but i want to send you an example to show what do i mean

Comment: and i think you speak arabic so you can understand me better

Comment: you can ask me here. if my answer helped you please vote it up.

Comment: okay, but the problem is i want to show you an example of what i mean, beacuse when i count the number of ones in the array im testing it has 10 ones as columns and seven one as rows

Comment: okay i edited my question and added the example of the array, if you count the one, there are 10 ones as a column, and 7 ones as rows @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @RAMA: I count 13 1s in the array. I don't understand what meaning the numbers 7 and 10 have in your example. The maximum number of 1s in a single column is 10, but what does the number 7 mean?

Comment: yeah there are 13 ones in the array that’s true, but there are 10 ones represented as column, and 7 ones represented in rows @AndreasWenzel

Comment: Never mind no one is getting what i mean

Comment: anyways thank for the help

Comment: @RAMA: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "respresented as column" and "represented in rows". I guess that "respresented as column" means that 10 1s are in the same column, but I have no idea what "represented in rows" means, because the maximum number of 1s in a single column is 2, not 7.

Comment: no problem, its okay thank for the help @AndreasWenzel

Comment: the sum of ones in the first row = you pass over the first row checking if the element is equal to 1 if its true increasing the counter. iterate this operation over all the rows (reset the counter after each row).and then make the same algorithm on the columns